# How can I import iPhone notes to my app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, import

Is it possible to import a note from iPhone notes app to my app? I googled a lot to get an idea about it. Nothing helps. Can someone give any idea about it?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The Notes app data is likely stored in its own filesystem directory - a directory to which your app does not have access privileges.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Third-party apps do not have access to the notes database. There is no public API for accessing the notes data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a flow for syncing apps (eg. [ifttt.com](http://ifttt.com)).

Create a rule that says "If a new note has been created (if a Gmail message has the label 'notes'), forward it to my db."

The solution is very clunky, but it's a starting point.
You could then find a way to scale this for your app.